# How to specify a port number in SQL Server connection string?

Tags: sql-server

I use the following connection string in SQL Server Management Studio. It failed to connect:

`mycomputer.test.xxx.com:1234\myInstance1`

But the following one is ok:

`mycomputer.test.xxx.com\myInstance1`

So how do I specify a port number in a connection string?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/89576

Answer (score 327, accepted):

Use a comma to specify a port number with SQL Server:

`mycomputer.test.xxx.com,1234`

It's not necessary to specify an instance name when specifying the port.

Lots more examples at http://www.connectionstrings.com/. It's saved me a few times.

Comment: Each instance must be on a separate port, so port=instance in Sql server.  I never knew this ",port" until now, though - thank you.

Comment: @Daniel: yep, you need to specify either port or instance.

Comment: Note: instance name is *ignored* when port is specified. So "mycomputer.test.xxx.com\AnyOldRubbish,1234" still works.

Comment: How does this work if the default (MSSQLSERVER) instance isn't running on 1433?

Comment: "not necessary to specify an instance name "  That was key for me.  FreeTDS on Raspi will crash if you put in the instance name and a port.  Never knew you could skip the instance name, and that's the only way to get it working in FreeTDS.

Comment: Having connectionString="Server=address\SQlExpress,1433" won't work.

Comment: Having MSSQLLocalDB, SQL Express and SQL Server 2019 Developer, all with default port set: specifying port in any case won't work, at least using "Data Source=". Always need to specify instance, without port. If port is specified, following exception is shown: 

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: Anyone have a link to the specs for this:"It's not necessary to specify an instance name when specifying the port."? 

Would be nice to know.

Comment: Ran into this issue today and was immediately disgruntled, I'm glad I'm not alone @PrgTrdr

Comment: For example, you would use this format for an OLEDB data connection in SSIS.

Answer (score 12):

For JDBC the proper format is slightly different and as follows:

```
jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://mycomputer.test.xxx.com:49843
```

Note the colon instead of the comma.

Comment: I have turned from C# to Java, and this answer saves me. Again.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped.  Not exactly intuitive documentation in Java for the JDBC connection string.  Not sure why it's different either, which is annoying.

Answer (score 4):

The correct SQL connection string for SQL with specify port is use comma between ip address and port number like following pattern: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,yyyy