# Connecting to SQL Server 2012 using sqlalchemy and pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2012 database using SQLAlchemy (with pyodbc) on Python 3.3 (Windows 7-64-bit).  I am able to connect using straight pyodbc but have been unsuccessful at connecting using SQLAlchemy.  I have dsn file setup for the database access.

I successfully connect using straight pyodbc like this:

```
con = pyodbc.connect('FILEDSN=c:\\users\\me\\mydbserver.dsn')
```

For sqlalchemy I have tried:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://c/users/me/mydbserver.dsn/mydbname')
```

The `create_engine` method doesn't actually set up the connection and succeeds, but
iIf I try something that causes sqlalchemy to actually setup the connection (like `engine.table_names()`), it takes a while but then returns this error:

`DBAPIError: (Error) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect)') None None`

I'm not sure where thing are going wrong are how to see what connection string is actually being passed to pyodbc by sqlalchemy.  I have successfully using the same sqlalchemy classes with SQLite and MySQL.

Comment: I found the SQLAlchemy documentation to be woefully inadequate on this topic.  Improvements there are warranted.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The file-based DSN string is being interpreted by SQLAlchemy as server name = `c`, database name = `users`.

I prefer connecting without using DSNs, it's one less configuration task to deal with during code migrations.

This syntax works using Windows Authentication:

```
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://server/database')
```

Or with SQL Authentication:

```
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@server/database')
```

SQLAlchemy has a thorough explanation of the different connection string options [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc).

Comment: Thanks.  The SQL Server instance is the only one that is not on the machine I am working on so I wasn't sure if there was something funny going on here.  Just to expand a little on the stings you listed (since sql server instances are apparently named) - `sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://[machinename]\\[servername]/[database]')`

Comment: They don't have to be named. It's actually easier to connect to and use a sql server instance configured as a "default instance". Named instances are required when you will be hosting multiple sql server instances on one server.

Comment: That link is broken. I think this is a suitable replacement: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#database-urls

Comment: `engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@server/database')` <br>
you have to add this
`?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0`
so final will be
`engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@server/database?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')`

Comment: @Bryan In reference to the synax you mentioned `engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@server/database')`, what if the password has `@` in it? what can I do? Its being parsed wrongly by alchemy.
EDIT: found the solution in the docs link, there is option to pass string to pyodbc directly to abvoid misinterpretations.

Answer (score 53):

In Python 3 you can use function [`quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) from module `urllib.parse` to create parameters for connection:

```
import urllib
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                                 "SERVER=dagger;"
                                 "DATABASE=test;"
                                 "UID=user;"
                                 "PWD=password")

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
```

In order to use Windows Authentication, you want to use *Trusted_Connection* as parameter:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                                 "SERVER=dagger;"
                                 "DATABASE=test;"
                                 "Trusted_Connection=yes")
```

In Python 2 you should use function [`quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) from library `urllib` instead:

```
params = urllib.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                           "SERVER=dagger;"
                           "DATABASE=test;"
                           "UID=user;"
                           "PWD=password")
```

Comment: For python 3, we should use urllib.parse.quote_plus

Comment: This may require special attention to the character encoding, e.g. add ".encode('utf-8')"

Answer (score 28):

I have an update info about the connection to MSSQL Server without using DSNs and using Windows Authentication. In my example I have next options:
My local server name is "(localdb)\ProjectsV12". Local server name I see from database properties (I am using Windows 10 / Visual Studio 2015).
My db name is "MainTest1"

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://(localdb)\ProjectsV12/MainTest1?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0', echo=True)
```

It is needed to specify driver in connection.
You may find your client version in:

> control panel>Systems and Security>Administrative Tools.>ODBC Data
>   Sources>System DSN tab>Add

Look on SQL Native client version from the list.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. Many thanks!

Comment: In my case`?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0` was the bit of string I was looking for. Was too slack to find my old code :D

Comment: @SupunDeSilva this is exactly what I needed myself. Thank you so much. I wish I could have upvoted your comment and andrew 's answer 10000 times.

Comment: Note, other driver locations on *NIX systems work well also. On OSX I used `driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so`

Answer (score 9):

Just want to add some latest information here:
If you are connecting using DSN connections:

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SOME_DSN")
```

If you are connecting using Hostname connections:

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST_IP:PORT/DATABASENAME?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0")
```

For more details, please refer to the ["Official Document"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html)

Comment: This answer helped me  but just adding that if someone is mentioning `port` as well then it should be given as `hostname,port` and not as `hostname:port`. mssql expects a comma and not colon.

Comment: @shshnk, I have checked both `hostname,port` and `hostname:port` on my mac, both worked.

Comment: I am surprised that `:` worked. For sql server even if you see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294721/how-to-specify-a-port-number-in-sql-server-connection-string .  The answer is to use a `,`. I am using `ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server` if that makes any difference.

Comment: @shshnk the comma is automatically translated somehow, its considered as like part of hostname i believe thats why both solutions work

Answer (score 4):

I did different and worked like a charm.

#### First you import the library:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc
```

#### Create a function to create the engine

```
def mssql_engine(user = os.getenv('user'), password = os.getenv('password')
                 ,host = os.getenv('SERVER_ADDRESS'),db = os.getenv('DATABASE')):
    engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{password}@{host}/{db}?driver=SQL+Server')
    return engine
```

#### Create a variable with your query

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM [Orders]'
```

#### Execute the Pandas command to create a Dataframe from a MSSQL Table

```
df = pd.read_sql(query, mssql_engine())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pyodbc 
import sqlalchemy as sa
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://ServerName/DatabaseName?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0',echo = True)
```

This works with Windows Authentication.