# PyOdbc fails to connect to a sql server instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a sql server instance using pyodbc version 3.0.6., SQLAlchemy 1.0.4 on Windows 7 using a Python 2.7 (32 bit). I am using a connection string as follows

```
    DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=mymachinename;DATABASE=mydb;UID=sa;PWD=admin1;
```

but I keep getting this error

> Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=mymachinename;DATABASE=mydb;UID=sa;PWD=admin1'

I am using the connection string with sqlSoup.Something like this

```
    db = sqlsoup.SQLSoup(connectionstring)
```

**Edit**
I tried using [Automap](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html) from SqlAlchemy and it also fails with the same message

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Sandbox\Python scripts\BumpValues\newConnectivityTest.py", line 7, in 
>       engine = create_engine("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=gagan;DATABASE=persons;UID=sa;PWD=admin1;")
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine__init__.py", line 386, in create_engine
>       return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 49, in create
>       u = url.make_url(name_or_url)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 176, in make_url
>       return _parse_rfc1738_args(name_or_url)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 225, in _parse_rfc1738_args
>       "Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '%s'" % name)
>   sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=gagan;DATABASE=persons;UID=sa;PWD=admin1;'
>   [Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
>   [shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Sandbox\Python scripts\BumpValues\newConnectivityTest.py"]

and my code is as follows

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


Base = automap_base()
engine = create_engine("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=gagan;DATABASE=persons;UID=sa;PWD=admin1;")
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

usrs = Base.classes.users
print(usrs)
```

Can you please let me know what am I doing wrong here ?

**Edit**
I would suggest this is not a duplicate of the question that Bryan has suggested is a duplicate of . For example , I am following the same example as was suggested in the question

```
    import sqlalchemy as sa
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://sa:admin1@gagan/persons')
```

but even it fails with the same message

Here are the snapshots .. 
the first one uses the connection string of type "'mssql+pyodbc://user:password@server/database'"

[image]

while the second one uses the connection string of type 
'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=gagan;DATABASE=people;UID=sa;PWD=admin1;

[image]

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to SQL Server 2012 using sqlalchemy and pyodbc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750711/connecting-to-sql-server-2012-using-sqlalchemy-and-pyodbc)

Comment: There's no way that the code using connection string `mssql+pyodbc://sa:admin1@gagan/persons` would fail with the same error message as the original. Double check the error message using the updated code sample and provide an updated message.

Comment: I have updated the question.. Sorry snapshots took some time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, this seems to have resolved the issue

```
import urllib    
connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};Database=people;SERVER=gagan;UID=sa;PWD=admin1"
connection_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string) 
connection_string = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % connection_string
```

Comment: I get the  error `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'quote_plus'` on this one

Comment: `quote_plus` is now included in `parse`.
use `urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)`
refer to https://github.com/web2py/web2py/issues/1822#issuecomment-370919823

Answer (score 1):

There are other drivers available in Windows ecosystem, you can try the other 2 as well :)

> There are actually two or three SQL Server drivers written and
> distrubuted by Microsoft: one referred to as "SQL Server" and the
> other as "SQL Native Client" and "SQL Server Native Client 10.0}".
>
> DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=cloak;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password
>
> DRIVER={SQL Native Client};SERVER=dagger;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password
>
> DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=dagger;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings

EDIT: 1

Since SQLSoup which is written on top of SQLAlchemy you will have to use the following connection string:

```
"mssql+pyodbc://sa:admin1@mymachinename/mydb"
```

Reference: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc