# Database engine fails to connect to a sql-server instance while trying to insert using to_sql function

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, database-connection

I am trying to insert pandas dataframe `CAPE` into `SQL Server` DB using dataframe.to_SQL. I have referred the following solution to insert rows.
[PyOdbc fails to connect to a sql server instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465284/pyodbc-fails-to-connect-to-a-sql-server-instance)

But I am getting an error shown below.

Source code:

```
   CAPE    # Input dataframe
   connection = pdc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};''Server=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;''Database=Tableau;''uid=SQL_User;pwd=Greentableau!')
   connection_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection)
   connection_string = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % connection_string
   engine = sq.create_engine(connection_string)
   CAPE.to_sql(engine, name='[Tableau].[dbo].[Company_Table]',if_exists='replace')
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Abhay\Python36-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 803, in quote_plus
string = quote(string, safe + space, encoding, errors)
  File "C:\Users\Abhay\Python36-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 787, in quote
 return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "C:\Users\Abhay\Python36-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 812, in quote_from_bytes
  raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
  TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
  connection = pdc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};''Server=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;''Database=Tableau;''uid=SQL_User;pwd=Greentableau!')
   connection_string = ur.quote(connection)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Abhay\Python36-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 787, in quote
return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "C:\Users\Abhay\Python36-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 812, in 
 quote_from_bytes
  raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
  TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

Sample Dataframe value:

```
        Date Company Value     Category BICS_LEVEL_1_SECTOR_NAME BICS_LEVEL_2_INDUSTRY_GROUP_NAME BICS_LEVEL_3_INDUSTRY_NAME BICS_LEVEL_4_SUB_INDUSTRY_NAME BICS_LEVEL_5_SEGMENT_NAME BICS_REVENUE_LEVEL_ASSIGNED BS_TOT_VAL_OF_SHARES_REPURCHASED COUNTRY COUNTRY_OF_LARGEST_REVENUE EQY_SH_OUT GICS_INDUSTRY_GROUP_NAME        GICS_INDUSTRY_NAME GICS_SECTOR_NAME    GICS_SUB_INDUSTRY_NAME      ICB_SECTOR_NAME            INDUSTRY_GROUP INDUSTRY_SECTOR INDUSTRY_SECTOR_NUM        INDUSTRY_SUBGROUP MARKET_SECTOR_DES Real_Earnings Real_Price  CAPE_10  Percentile_10_CAPE
        0 1975-04-30   3M Co     0          EPS                Materials                        Chemicals        Specialty Chemicals           Adhesives & Sealants                       NaN                       10399                          3635.82      US              United States    596.767            Capital Goods  Industrial Conglomerates      Industrials  Industrial Conglomerates  General Industrials  Miscellaneous Manufactur      Industrial               10011  Diversified Manufact Op            Equity             0          0      NaN                 NaN
        1 1975-04-30   3M Co     0  Stock Price                Materials                        Chemicals        Specialty Chemicals           Adhesives & Sealants                       NaN                       10399                          3635.82      US              United States    596.767            Capital Goods  Industrial Conglomerates      Industrials  Industrial Conglomerates  General Industrials  Miscellaneous Manufactur      Industrial               10011  Diversified Manufact Op            Equity             0          0      NaN                 NaN
        2 1975-04-30   3M Co     0    Cash Flow                Materials                        Chemicals        Specialty Chemicals           Adhesives & Sealants                       NaN                       10399                          3635.82      US              United States    596.767            Capital Goods  Industrial Conglomerates      Industrials  Industrial Conglomerates  General Industrials  Miscellaneous Manufactur      Industrial               10011  Diversified Manufact Op            Equity             0          0      NaN                 NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first positional parameter of [DataFrame.to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) is a table name, you passed `engine` (SQLAlchemy object) as a first parameter.

So try this instead:

```
CAPE.to_sql('[Tableau].[dbo].[Company_Table]',con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: I am getting error in 'urllib.parse.quote_plus()' line, before calling to_sql. Is there any better way to insert data frame into Sql-server Db

Comment: I have changed my code to following 
 `params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;DATABASE=Tableau;UID=SQL_User;PWD=Greentableau!")
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
engine.connect()
df.to_sql(name='[Tableau].[dbo].[Test table]',con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append') `
Now it works fine