# Need help in inserting Pandas Dataframe into Sql-server DB in python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sql-insert

I am trying to insert pandas dataframe `CAPE` into `SQL Server` DB using dataframe.to_SQL.   I have referred the following solution to insert rows.
[PyOdbc fails to connect to a sql server instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465284/pyodbc-fails-to-connect-to-a-sql-server-instance) .But i am getting error in `urllib.parse.quote_plus` line.

Can anyone help provide a solution to insert dataframe in Sql-server DB.

Source code:

```
   CAPE    # Input dataframe
   connection = pdc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};''Server=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;''Database=Tableau;''uid=SQL_User;pwd=Greentableau!')
   connection_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection)
   connection_string = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % connection_string
   engine = sq.create_engine(connection_string)
   CAPE.to_sql(engine, name='[Tableau].[dbo].[Company_Table]',if_exists='replace')
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Abhay\Python36-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 803, in quote_plus
string = quote(string, safe + space, encoding, errors)
  File "C:\Users\Abhay\Python36-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 787, in quote
 return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "C:\Users\Abhay\Python36-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 812, in quote_from_bytes
  raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
  TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
  connection = pdc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};''Server=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;''Database=Tableau;''uid=SQL_User;pwd=Greentableau!')
   connection_string = ur.quote(connection)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Abhay\Python36-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 787, in quote
return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "C:\Users\Abhay\Python36-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 812, in 
 quote_from_bytes
  raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
  TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

Sample Dataframe value:

```
        Date Company Value     Category BICS_LEVEL_1_SECTOR_NAME BICS_LEVEL_2_INDUSTRY_GROUP_NAME BICS_LEVEL_3_INDUSTRY_NAME BICS_LEVEL_4_SUB_INDUSTRY_NAME BICS_LEVEL_5_SEGMENT_NAME BICS_REVENUE_LEVEL_ASSIGNED BS_TOT_VAL_OF_SHARES_REPURCHASED COUNTRY COUNTRY_OF_LARGEST_REVENUE EQY_SH_OUT GICS_INDUSTRY_GROUP_NAME        GICS_INDUSTRY_NAME GICS_SECTOR_NAME    GICS_SUB_INDUSTRY_NAME      ICB_SECTOR_NAME            INDUSTRY_GROUP INDUSTRY_SECTOR INDUSTRY_SECTOR_NUM        INDUSTRY_SUBGROUP MARKET_SECTOR_DES Real_Earnings Real_Price  CAPE_10  Percentile_10_CAPE
        0 1975-04-30   3M Co     0          EPS                Materials                        Chemicals        Specialty Chemicals           Adhesives & Sealants                       NaN                       10399                          3635.82      US              United States    596.767            Capital Goods  Industrial Conglomerates      Industrials  Industrial Conglomerates  General Industrials  Miscellaneous Manufactur      Industrial               10011  Diversified Manufact Op            Equity             0          0      NaN                 NaN
        1 1975-04-30   3M Co     0  Stock Price                Materials                        Chemicals        Specialty Chemicals           Adhesives & Sealants                       NaN                       10399                          3635.82      US              United States    596.767            Capital Goods  Industrial Conglomerates      Industrials  Industrial Conglomerates  General Industrials  Miscellaneous Manufactur      Industrial               10011  Diversified Manufact Op            Equity             0          0      NaN                 NaN
        2 1975-04-30   3M Co     0    Cash Flow                Materials                        Chemicals        Specialty Chemicals           Adhesives & Sealants                       NaN                       10399                          3635.82      US              United States    596.767            Capital Goods  Industrial Conglomerates      Industrials  Industrial Conglomerates  General Industrials  Miscellaneous Manufactur      Industrial               10011  Diversified Manufact Op            Equity             0          0      NaN                 NaN
```

I am using SQL server version 13.0.4

**Version 2:**

I have updated my code. Now its giving `sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError:`

Code:

```
  import pyodbc
  import sqlalchemy

   CAFE # sample dataframe
   engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://SQL_User:Greentableau!@GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com/Tableau?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0")
   engine.connect()
   CAPE.to_sql(name='[Tableau].[dbo].[Test_table]',con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

> Error:

```
     sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: what is you SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL server version 13.0.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no need to quote a connection string.

Here is an example from [SQL Alchemy online docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc):

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@myhost:port/databasename?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0")
```

I.e. we don't have to call/use PyODBC directly - SQL Alchemy will do it for us...

PS [the driver name will depend on your SQL Server version...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41729710/5741205)

**UPDATE:** thanks to [@ArvinthKumar - here is the connection string that finally worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667144/need-help-in-inserting-pandas-dataframe-into-sql-server-db-in-python/45670669?noredirect=1#comment78360759_45670669):

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;DATABASE=Tableau;UID=SQ‌​‌​L_User;PWD=sql_password')
```

Comment: I have changed my code to following   `params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;DATABASE=Tableau;UID=SQ‌​L_User;PWD=Greentabl‌​eau!") engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params) engine.connect() df.to_sql(name='[Tableau].[dbo].[Test table]',con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')` Now it works fine

Comment: @ArvinthKumar, thanks for the update! Could you also post an output of `print("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)` - this might be helpful for those having the same issue in future?

Comment: Output of `print("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)` Statement : `Engine(mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;DATABASE=Tableau;UID=SQL_User;PWD=Greentableau!)`

Comment: @ArvinthKumar, so if you try `conn = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;DATABASE=Tableau;UID=SQ‌​L_User;PWD=Greentabl‌​eau!')` - does it work properly?

Comment: @ArvinthKumar, thanks for testing! I'll update my answer. I hope it might help someone in future...