# Python sqlalchemy trying to write pandas dataframe to SQL Server using .to_sql

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a python code through which I am getting a pandas dataframe "df". I am trying to write this dataframe to Microsoft SQL server. I am trying to connect through the following code by I am getting an error

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=bidept;DATABASE=BIDB;UID=sdcc\neils;PWD=neil!pass')
engine.connect()
df.to_sql(name='[BIDB].[dbo].[Test]',con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

However at the engine.connect() line I am getting the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 14.0.17177.0

I connect to the SQL server through the following

```
Server type: Database Engine
Server name: bidept
Authentication: Windows Authentication

for which I log into my windows using username : sdcc\neils
and password : neil!pass
```

I am new to databases and python. Kindly let me know if you need any additional details. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to SQL server from SQLAlchemy: "Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416699/connecting-to-sql-server-from-sqlalchemy-neither-dsn-nor-server-keyword-suppli)

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to make it run.

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib

params = urllib.quote_plus(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=bidept;DATABASE=BIDB;Trusted_Connection=yes')
### For python 3.5: urllib.parse.quote_plus 
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = create_engine(conn_str)
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

df.to_sql(name='Test',con=engine, if_exists='append',index=False)
```

Thanks to @gord-thompson who answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416699/need-help-writing-pandas-dataframe-into-sql-server-using-python)

Although my in my sql server, all the tables are under the 'dbo' schema (i.e. dbo.Test1, dbo.Other_Tables) and this query puts my table in 'sdcc\neils' schema (i.e. sdcc\neils.Test1, sdcc\neils.Other_Tables) any solution to this?

Comment: solution `df.to_sql(name='Test',con=engine, if_exists='append',index=False, schema="dbo")`