# Why to_sql is not working with pyodbc in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyodbc

I have an excel file. Im importing that to dataframe and trying to update a database table using the data.

```
import pyodbc

def get_sale_file():


    try:
            cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
                      'SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + uname + ';PWD=' + pword,
                      autocommit=False)

        files = os.listdir(ile_path)
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        for f in files:
            if (f.endswith('.xlsx') or f.endswith('.xls')):
                df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(sap_file_path, f))
                df.to_sql('temptable', cnxn, if_exists='replace')

        query = "UPDATE MList AS mas" + \
                " SET TTY = temp.[Territory Code] ," + \
                " Freq =temp.[Frequency Code]," + \

                " FROM temptable AS temp" + \
                " WHERE mas.SiteCode = temp.[ri a]"
```

When I execute above code block; I get

```
1/12/2019 10:19:45 AM  ERROR: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Am i trying in right way? Does panads have any other function to update mssql table other than `to_sql?`
How can I overcome above error?

**Edit**
Should i have to create temptable beforehand to load datafarme? If that so, my file contains 100s of column, it may vary..(except few columns) How could I make sure pandas to load only few columns to temptable?

Comment: You can use sqlalchemy, see this on how to make the connection
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750711/connecting-to-sql-server-2012-using-sqlalchemy-and-pyodbc

Comment: Are you sure that cnxn contains some?...

Comment: Are you trying to access an sqlite database with a SQL Server driver? The error is saying that sqlite_master is not valid. If so Python has built in sqlite support and there is no need to use ODBC.

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar sorry my bad, I think I have to create temptable in database before loading  file to dataframe?If that so, my file contains 100s of column, it may vary..(except few columns) How could I make sure pandas to load only few columns to temptable?

Comment: Check the parameter 'con' un this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: Here you have an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402225/python-sqlalchemy-trying-to-write-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-server-using-to-sql

Comment: I wrote the code here .. https://pastebin.com/wJvBVm1i   , I recommend you first run the script alone.

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar using urllib+sqlalchemy+pyodbc it is working thanks a lot. You could post your pastebin answer here.  urllib.parse.quote_plus is working

Comment: @Ratha , thank ...I will update the code bellow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the guide of pandas.DataFrame.to_sql (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) , the connection expect a connection type sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlite3.Connection , then is necesary change your code using a connection like this :

```
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
cnxn = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://<username>:<password>@<dsnname>")


df.to_sql("table_name", cnxn,if_exists='replace')
```

UPDATE : Using urllib

```
import urllib
import pyodbc

params = urllib.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=yourserver;DATABASE=yourdatabase ;UID=user;PWD=password")
cnxn = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)

df.to_sql("table_name", cnxn,if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: When i switch to sqlalchemey to get connection parameter i get  ERROR: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found,
 and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

Comment: Im using MAC machine

Comment: but you have installed the ODBC ?

Comment: What library then I need to install? Im running python program in the virtual environment. I have pyodbc inplace already, which is working for another DB process

Comment: check this link https://kite.com/python/docs/sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc   ...how is calling the DRIVER , using import urllib

Comment: Any chance to get the code example from the link running for a as/400 database? If I'm trying to use pandas.to_sql with the connection from the link, I cannot provide a schema and the execution of the generated sql statement fails

Answer (score 0):

You can try another package, too, instead of pyodbc, e.g. pytds or adodbapi.
The first one is very simple, with adodbapi the connection config looks like

```
from adodbapi import adodbapi as adba

raw_config_adodbapi = f"PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source={server};Initial Catalog={database};trusted_connection=no;User ID={user};Password={password};"
conn = adba.connect(raw_config_adodbapi, timeout=120, autocommit=True)
```

Besides, it seems like the parameters in the connections string in pyodbc should be enclosed in {}, but maybe it's not mandatory.

Comment: I think issue is , i have to create temptable beforehand to load datafarme? If that so, my file contains 100s of column, it may vary..(except few columns) How could I make sure pandas to load only few columns to temptable?