# Writing data to a SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, sql-server-2016

So I am trying to write a data frame to Microsoft SQL Server using the pandas `to_sql` function.

I have created an engine using

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
  'mssql:///Server/Database?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
)

con = engine.connect()

switchers.to_sql('check',engine)
```

The error I am getting is as follows :

> OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].  (2) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (2)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Any idea what I should be looking for?

Comment: First obvious question: Have you created a server?

Comment: Yes mate, its for an organization so the server already exists with data

Comment: Can you actually communicate with this server? There can be set strict permissions especially when this is production DB.

Comment: That connection string looks a bit dodgy, where's the authentication? I don't know pandas but SQL server does like a nice connection string :-). I also had a look over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750711/connecting-to-sql-server-2012-using-sqlalchemy-and-pyodbc which has a nice answer that may suit what you are doing

Comment: OMG, the error was writing it as SQL Server Native Client 11.0 instead of SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string should be:

```
engine = 
    sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://Server/Database?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
```