# NameError: name 'create_engine' is not defined,

Tags: python, sql-server, anaconda, alchemy

I am attempting to create a python script that connects to an MS SQL Studio database and using SQLAlchemy to help with this. (I am learning databases and python), but I am trying to create a connection to a new database but keep getting this "create_engine" is not defined in SQLAlchemy error.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd

SERVER = 'BEAST-ACTIVE\SQLEXPRESS'  #FIND SERVER NAME
DATABASE = 'SQLTUTORIAL' #DATABASE TO CONNECT TO
DRIVER = 'SQL Server' #FIND DRIVER 
USERNAME = 'abcd'
PASSWORD = 'abcd123'
DATABASE_CONNECTION = f'msql://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{SERVER}/{DATABASE}?driver={DRIVER}'

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_CONNECTION)
connection = engine.connect()
data = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from 
[SQLTUTORIAL].[dbo].[EmployeeDemographics] 
order by [EmployeeID]", connection)
data.dtypese
```

OUTPUT:

```
NameError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 engine = 
create_engine(DATABASE_CONNECTION)
      2 connection = engine.connect()
      3 data = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * 
from [SQLTUTORIAL].[dbo]. 
[EmployeeDemographics] order by 
[EmployeeID]", connection)

NameError: name 'create_engine' is not defined
```

I am using Anaconda Jupyter Notebook 6.4.8 and MSSQLMS 18.12.1

Comment: it gives you an error when trying to use it but not when importing it? The error that I have running your code is because you are doing `DATABASE_CONNECTION = f'msql://` instead of `DATABASE_CONNECTION = f'mssql://`  (notice the double s in mssql)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, I still get an error after adding the extra "s".  :(

Comment: The error says that the error is in cell line 1. It looks like you have your code separated in different cells and you are just running part of the code without having imported the libraries? You need to rerun the previous cells that contain the imports.

Comment: This any use - half way down.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750711/connecting-to-sql-server-2012-using-sqlalchemy-and-pyodbc

Comment: @JonTout you can link to specific answers by clicking on their `Share` link to see their URL. Is there a particular answer there you'd like to direct to OP to?

Comment: Your question edit broke the formatting somewhat and introduced errors to the code, such as `driver={DRIVER}` getting changed to `driver=DRIVER}`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the prerequisite drivers and Python packages yet?

To install the SQLAlchemy package you need to execute the following in a Jupyter console:

```bash
pip install sqlalchemy
```

If you want to use Microsoft's more modern ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (or 18) for connectivity you need to download and install the appropriate driver [from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) and then install the pyodbc package from a Jupyter console:

```bash
pip install pyodbc
```

And then also change the line `DRIVER = 'SQL Server' #FIND DRIVER` to `DRIVER = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' #FIND DRIVER`

The last line of your script also contains a typo: `data.dtypese` should be `data.dtypes`