# SQL Alchemy create database connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Im new in using sql alchemy and i am starting with creating connection. I encounter challenge in creating the connection string and I am not sure if the format of the connection string is correct. Specifically my error is the server cannot be found, but when I try it using pyodbc, the credentials are correct(credentials here are dummy only for posting purposes).

I also wanna know what can be the code to prompt if my connection is success or not. I am connecting to MS SQL SERVER.

```
import urllib
import sqlalchemy as sal
import pyodbc


# DEFINE THE DATABASE CREDENTIALS
user = 'user'
password = 'pass'
host = 'hostname'
port = 'port'
database = 'TEST_DB'

connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL 
Server};SERVER=host:port;DATABASE=database;UID=user;PWD=password"
connection_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string) 
connection_string = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % connection_string




try:

engine = sal.create_engine(connection_string)
connection = engine.connect()
print("Passed")

except:
print("failed!")
```

Comment: Solve this your question, [sof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15750953/20851944)

Answer (score 0):

You can format the connection string like this:`f"mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}?driver=SQL+Server"`

Don't forget to put a `connection.close()` at the end and it is also a good idea to print out a traceback when an error occurs.