# Connecting MS Access 2007 to SQL Server 2008 (a named instance not using port 1433)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have to setup my connection string correctly to link MS Access 2007 tables to a SQL Server 2008 backend named instance using a DSN-Less connection

The sql server instance is not using port 1433, so I need to specify the port number in the connection string (port 4142)

```
ConnectStr = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}" _
& ";SERVER=ServerName\InstanceName,PortNo." _
& ";DATABASE=database" _
& ";Trusted_Connection=yes;"
```

This did not work and I got an ODBC Error No. 3151.

Am I able to specify the port number this way
Or do I have to use another driver if I have to specify the port number the sql server is listening on.

Thanks

Geoff

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no need specify the instance name if you're giving the port number. Could be worth a shot.

```
ConnectStr = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}" _
& ";SERVER=ServerName,PortNo." _
& ";DATABASE=database" _
& ";Trusted_Connection=yes;"
```

Refer to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294721/how-to-specify-a-port-number-in-sql-server-connection-string) for more info.