# EF somehow connecting to the wrong SQL Server instance, even though connection string says it's correct?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

Scenario:

- Single SQL Server with 2 instances -> `.\test` & `.\live`
- Single IIS server with 2 websites -> `test` & `live`

`test` website's `web.config` points to the `.\test` SQL server instance, `live` website points to `.\live`. The SQL Server instances are identical in every way, i.e. DB names, SQL username / password, etc. The only way they differ is by the ports they listen on.

We have the following code deployed to the `test` website:

```
_logger.Debug("connection string: " + _context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);

_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("stored_procedure @param");
```

When we check the logfile after this code has executed, it shows that the connection string is pointing to the `.\test` instance, as expected. But a SQL Profiler trace shows that `stored_procedure` is being executed against the `.\live` instance.

We can't figure out why or how this is happening, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing piece of the puzzle was the ports. As per the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5294741/70345), MSSQL ports and instances are the same thing... and **port overrides instance name if specified**.

Our connection strings looked like the following:

`test`: `Data Source=server\test,7777;Initial Catalog=ourdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass`
`live`: `Data Source=server\live,7777;Initial Catalog=ourdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass`

So although they were pointing to different instances, the same **port** overrode that and forced them both to effectively point at whatever was running on port 7777 - i.e. the `.\live` instance, hence the anomalous behavior we experienced.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510203.aspx gives a pretty reasonable overview of how instance names and ports correlate.