# Determine the Port number a SqlConnection is connected to

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

In some part of my code, I have a SqlConnection object that is open.
How do I find out the port of the Sql Server Instance it is connected to?

Answer (score 1):

you can query it;

```
USE master
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on' 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

By default it will be connected to TCP port `1433`. Well not sure if there is any other better way present but you can get this information from registry entry key `TcpPort` from below registry path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLSERVER\SUPERSOCKETNETLIB\TCP
```

You can use [`Registry.GetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to read this information from system registry.

Comment: Have you tried checking the `ConnectionString` property?

Answer (score 0):

It will be port 1433 unless you have specified a different port in the connection string.

For information on connection string options see:
[How to specify a port number in SQL Server connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5294721/934912) and http://www.connectionstrings.com/