# VBA connection to SQL Server denied from other computer

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have a VBA macro that connects to a database to pull some data and works fine. However, when another person from another department tries to run the file from his computer, he gets an error:

[image: Here is the message]

My VBA connection string is the following:

```
Sub exportLens()
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String
Sheets("data").Range("A2:C100000").Clear

ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SQLxxx;Data Source=xx.xx5.xx.90,xx33;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=NasrWeb"
```

Any idea, why this is not working from my friend's computer?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can he ping the server you are trying to connect to?

Comment: Use Windows Authentication if possible. Don't store passwords and user ID's in a connection string in VBA code. VBA code, even protected, is not secure.

Comment: The DataSource should be xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx (semicolon) not xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxxx (comma)

Comment: no. comma is correct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294721/how-to-specify-a-port-number-in-sql-server-connection-string

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of these things:

1. Remote connection is not enabled for a SQL Server instance.
2. Port is not added in the firewall exception list
3. IP address of the SQL Server Instance is blocked the Firewall

Comment: Wouldn't either of these things cause the OP to also experience the same connection problems?