# Connecting to a second instance of SQL Server remotely

Tags: sql-server

I got 2 instances (SQL Server 2012 and 2014) installed in my PC, and they both have different port numbers. I am having issues connecting to the second one.

A bit more in detail:

SQL Server 2012:

- Name -> AUG001
- Port no. -> 1221

SQL Server 2014:

- Name -> AUG001\Cardiff
- Port no. -> 1331

I am able to connect to the first one (SQL Server 2012) remotely and select the databases while installing the app.

But I can't get the second one to display the databases in it.

The connection string would be something like this for SQL Server 2012 and it works:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=AUG001;Database=Catalog;UID=sa;PWD=london;Persist Security Info=True
```

But when I have a connection string as shown below for SQL Server 2014, it doesn't work:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=AUG001\Cardiff,<1331>;Database=Catalog;UID=sa;PWD=london;Persist Security Info=True
```

It doesn't display any rows from the catalog and I get the error, connection string is invalid

Any ideas please anyone?

Comment: Try Server=AUG001\Cardiff:1331 instead of the <1331> you've got now.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Same error-> Connection string invalid, parameter incorrect

Comment: Have you noticed that you have the <> around the 1331?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify a port number in SQL Server connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294721/how-to-specify-a-port-number-in-sql-server-connection-string)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo from edit I think. Corrected it now.

Comment: Go read Richard's link first - your port number is not correctly formatted. Generally you don't need to use port numbers if the sql server browser service is running. You also refer to "the app". So - can you access the second one using ssms, bcp, sqlcmd, or any other tool besides "the app"?

Comment: Try Server=AUG001\Cardiff:1331