# .NET Core 2 - Connection string with instance name and port number

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, database-connection

In my application I have a connection string in the config. This application created using .NET core 2.11 and SQL Server. This is the connection string:

```
Data Source=servername\instancename, portnumber;Initial Catalog=dbname;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password;
```

This string causes an error as shown here:

[image]

This error happens if I use instance name and port number in the string. If I remove either one, it is working. So, how do I make it work to used both instance name and port number in the connection string?

Comment: Have a look here for how to specify the port number: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5294741,  I would avoid the space between the comma and the actual number.  I'm not sure you can use a port number with an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Instance name will be use dynamic port, so I cannot use default port number (1433). Need to change the port number to used 1433 instead of the dynamic port.