# Connecting to SQL Server on a different port in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Thanks to the post found here:

[How do you specify a different port number in SQL Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89576/how-do-you-specify-a-different-port-number-in-sql-management-studio)

I figured out how to connect to a remote instance of SQL Server running on a different port when using SQL Server Management Studio. Adding a comma after the server name and then the port number did the trick.

SQLSERVER,port\InstanceName

The same thing does not work in SQL Server Reporting Services.  In reporting services it seems the comma indicates a password is coming next.  How do I specify the port number for my data source on the report server ?

Comment: Are you wanting to supply a port number _in addition_ to the instance name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax is the same as you would enter in SSMS. See below screenshot taken from the Data Source properties window:

[image]