# Couldn't connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

To All,

I did search before I posted my question, but couldn't find anything similar.

Here is my problem:

This is not a connection string for an application. It is the problem I tired to use the 
SQL Server Management Studio.

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 that runs on a Windows 2008 R2 server. I have tried to access the SQL Server from a Windows 7 client. It just couldn't connect using SQL Server Management Studio. I DON'T USE THE DEFAULT INSTANCE, SO THE PORT 1433 IS NOT USED. I OPENED THE PORT 12345 FOR SQL.

BUT I HAVE NO ANY PROBLEMS TO CONNECT USING  sqlcmd utility FROM THE SAME CLIENT.

What am I missing????

Appreciated for all your helps.

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT AT US ! Please, don't use ALL CAPS - it's considered SHOUTING at readers, and it's offensive and rude. Don't do it. Also: can you **please** show us what you use when you try to connect to your SQL Server? What do you type in for server/database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that you will need to include the port number as part of your connection string.  by default it will try and connect via 1433, but as use have stated that has been changed.  add `,12345` to the end of your `datasource=server` so you end up with smething like this
`datasource=servername,12345; ...etc`

Comment: Hi Nathan Fisher, thank you for such quick response. Please read my post carefully, I tried to connect using the SQL Server tool - SQL Server Management Studio. Where and how can you setup the port? Thanks.

Comment: ok within ssms its the same. put in the `<servername>,<port>` into the  server name textbox.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/89576/29467

Comment: Hi Nathan Fisher, you are the man!!!! The <servername>,<port> did the trick. Thank you so much.