# Cannot connect to named instance (2nd instance) from local SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have two instances:

1. Default
2. Named[dynamics\FINANCE]

running on SQL Server 2014. However, when I try to connect to named instance say (dynamics\FINANCE) using SQL authentication from local SSMS, I get below error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

I assigned a static port number 1450 to the named instance [dynamics\FINANCE]. I also setup the firewall rule to allow access to Port 1450.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try connecting to `dynamics\FINANCE,1450`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89576/how-do-you-specify-a-different-port-number-in-sql-management-studio

Comment: @BaconBits- It worked. Thanks a lot. One more question. Is it possible to run 2 instances on the same port 1433? My default instance is running on port 1433. Thanks, again

Comment: Not simultaneously, no. TCP/IP only allows one listener per socket. That's how the OS knows which process the data is for, and there's no super-server or service dispatcher to handle the negotiation between instances. If you want to use the same port, you could bind the second instance to a different IP address on your network card.  You could even set up DNS CNAMEs (or the hosts file if local) to control name resolution, but if you don't want to do that and still need TCP/IP then you need to use a different port.  Or you can run only one instance at a time.