# How to connect from SSMS to SQL Server database with connectionString="Data Source=ABC..." (instead of localhost)

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, ssms

Help me please to understand, what does it mean "ABC" in:

```
connectionString="Data Source=ABC;Initial Catalog=xyz; User ID=***; Password=***;"
```

How to connect to this SQL Server database using SSMS from another Windows computer? It's no trouble for me to connect to other databases with `"Data Source=localhost"`, but `"Data Source=ABC"` puzzles me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data Source` represents the instance name. If SQL Server is installed as `default instance`, the hostname alone is enough. If it is installed as a `named instance`, `hostname\instancename` should be provided.

If instance is running using a different port that the default one (`1433`), the [port number should be provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89576/how-do-you-specify-a-different-port-number-in-sql-management-studio).

More details can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/80767/what-are-named-and-default-instance) and [here](http://sqlandme.com/2013/05/01/sql-server-finding-tcp-port-number-sql-instance-is-listening-on/).

Comment: Ty Alexei, your answer (with links provided) is completely that I need to know.